# NERR_DCNotFound when attempting to join Windows Server 2010 domain using PBIS

Tags: active-directory, redhat, domain-controller, windows-server-2012, dns-server

I have a RHEL 6.3 Amazon Web Service instance I'm trying to join to a Windows Server 2012 AD domain through PowerBroker Identity Services Open (ie: not enterprise).

The Server 2012 instance is in the same subnet, I've opened TCP 88, 139, 389, 445, 464 and UDP 53, 88, 137, 445, 464 in the firewall.

When I run `domainjoin-cli join domain.com administrator` I receive the following:

```
Error: NERR_DCNotFound [code 0x00000995]
```

Is this an SRV record issue?

The Server 2012 instance (also running in AWS, in case there's any confusion about that) is running DNS and Active Directory, and the RHEL system is using that system as its name server.

Comment: Issue was resolved after adding 389 UDP (LDAP) to the inbound ports on the firewall rules used by both instances. Silly mistake...

Comment: Here's microsoft's list of required ports:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx